# I want an image next to a text using bootstrap, but why is it going on the next row?

Tags: bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap 5 and I'm trying to put an image next to a text, but when I insert "col-lg-6" on both cols, one column is going on the next row.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row bg-white">
  <div class="col-6">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" class="img-fluid" alt="">
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-6 mt-5 ms-5">
    <h2 class="fs-1 fw-light">Why Choose Us?</h2>
    <h4 class="fs-3 my-3 fw-bold">We are trusted by many customers</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="row bg-white">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 col-xxl-6">
    <img src="/images/section3/wheel.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 col-xxl-6 mt-5">
    <h2 class="fs-1 fw-light">Why Choose Us?</h2>
    <h4 class="fs-3 my-3 fw-bold">We are trusted by many customers</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please remove ms-5 class from your text because it leaves the space from left side (margin-left: 3rem!important;).

Answer (score 0):

By adding margin to a column you make it wider that the space left for it by the *other* half-width column. Use padding instead.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row bg-white">
  <div class="col-6">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" class="img-fluid" alt="">
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-6 pt-5 ps-5">
    <h2 class="fs-1 fw-light">Why Choose Us?</h2>
    <h4 class="fs-3 my-3 fw-bold">We are trusted by many customers</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```